# The element doesn't change color when scrolling back on top the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

[here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nw2gkLdu/41/)  I want to change the color of the "@" element on the page after I scroll the navigation bar.

[image]

It works but only when I scroll down.

[image]

When I scroll on top of the page it doesn't work.  As a result, @ stays red coloured when expected to be white.

[image]

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    if (!document.querySelector('.container')) return;
    let container = document.querySelector('.container');

    if (container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop === container.clientHeight) {
        document.querySelector('.chat-icon').style.color = "red";
    } else
        document.querySelector('.chat-icon').style.color = "white";
});
```

P.S. white element is the one of "container" class and violet is a navigation bar.

Comment: are you using reactJS?

Comment: Your code looks fine though. Mind providing a simple example at jsfiddle or somewhere? Would be easier to see it in action (including your markup btw).

Comment: @Aer0 You can now have a look at an example (link is provided in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would be because the div cannot be scrolled and the variable container.scrollTop returns 0 [mozzila docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

> If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow or if the element has a property of "non-scrollable"), scrollTop is 0.

instead you can use window.scrollY

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
let container = document.querySelector('.nav');
if (container.scrollHeight - window.scrollY === container.clientHeight) {
    document.querySelector('.chat-icon').style.color = "red";
} else
    document.querySelector('.chat-icon').style.color = "white";
});
```

[here's a working a example](https://jsfiddle.net/wadcpbLr/10/)

Comment: Thank you! It was definitely a cause. Now it's working fine.